# Computing Mode of Prior

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, mode

How do you compute the mode of a prior with beta distribution $(\alpha, \beta)$?

Comment: A beta prior is a very simple function; in this case, as long as the parameters are both greater than 1, you can do it by setting the derivative of the prior to 0. If one of the parameters is less than 1 the mode of the prior will be at an endpoint; it's also possible to have two modes.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mode_and_concentration), the mode of a beta distribution is:

$\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}\;$for $\;α, β > 1$

any value in $(0,1)$ for $\;α, β = 1$

$\{0, 1\}$ (bimodal) for $\;α, β < 1$

$0$ for $\;α ≤ 1, β > 1$

$1$ for $\;α > 1, β ≤ 1$

As an example, say $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta = 3$, then we would use the first formula because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are greater than $1$

$\frac{2-1}{2+3-2}=\frac{1}{3}$

Using wolfram alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=beta+distribution+%282%2C3%29) we can double check and see that we are correct.